# how to identify specific list element field and set its displaying objects's property to true

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angular, angular2-template

So using *ngFor i displayed the list of name property of object, this object also has a property named isAvailable I want to set isAvalable property to toggle between true and false when I click on it, and based on isAvalible a text next to li will display is available or not

```
<p>Authors</p>
<ul>
<li *ngFor='let author of authors' (click)='onClick()'>
{{author.name}}
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Authors</p>
<ul>

   <li *ngFor='let author of authors'>
        <span [hidden]='author.isAvalible'>{{author.name}}</span>
        <span (click)='onClick()'>author.isAvalible</span>
    </li>
</ul>


onClick(value){
   value=!value;
}
```

Comment: you can also handle click event in HTML template itself as shown in other answer.

Comment: So if there is click event and we are changing property based on this event, what happens, does list re-renders? and see if isAvailable property is true, display text next to it

Comment: List renders when page is loaded. Then based on click event you just toggle a particular `li`. you show it and hide it. list doesn't get rendered each time..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want this

```
<p>Authors</p>
<ul>
   <li *ngFor='let author of authors'>
     <span [hidden]='author.isAvalible'>{{author.name}}</span>
     <span (click)='author.isAvalible = !author.isAvalible '>author.isAvalible</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So if there is click event and we are changing property based on this event, what happens, does list re-renders? and see if isAvailable property is true, display text next to it

Comment: @blackHawk It will check the isAvalible for that item on which it is bound and will show or hide the `author.name`

Comment: How it happens I mean for individual item and recheck its dependencies

Comment: It will go through the list and see if it is true will show if is false hide